# Possible to configure VSCode path format when dragging and dropping file to integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When dragging and dropping a file from the VSCode explorer to the integrated terminal in Windows the path is not in the correct format. There is a leading forward slash.

For example:

/c:/temp/hello.py

This is inconvenient if you want to run this file or open it in another program.

Oddly dragging a folder is in the correct Windows format and uses backward slashes:

c:\temp

Is it possible to configure the format of the tfile path so that it doesn't include the leading forward slash?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue: [#29926](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29926) - try subscribing to that issue to receive updates.